# How can I programmatically count occurrences of all elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop, foreach

I'm working on a photography website in Angular 15/TS, and in the gallery there needs to be a list of filters that users can apply to see certain genres of photos (e.g. 'animal photos', 'nature photos', etc). The genres are determined by the website owner, and each time they upload a new photo they can tag it with an existing genre or create a new one. I am trying to use a forEach loop to create the list at runtime, like so:

```
  setFilterList() {
    const tempFilterList: Genre[] = [];
    this.photos.forEach((photo) => {
      const existingGenre = tempFilterList.find((entry) => {
        entry.name === photo.genre;
      });
      if (existingGenre) {
        existingGenre.quantity += 1;
      } else {
        tempFilterList.push({
          name: photo.genre || 'generic',
          quantity: 1,
        });
      }
    });
    this.filterList = tempFilterList;
  }
```

Genre is an interface with a string name and a number quantity. Basically, the HTML should show checkboxes in a list, like

```
<li><mat-checkbox>{{genre.name}} ({{genre.quantity}})</mat-checkbox></li>
```

for each unique genre. The problem with this method, as far as I can tell, is that the forEach loop is running to completion before the `tempFilterList` array updates. Because of this, instead of getting one 'nature' genre entry with a quantity of 9 (my test photoset has 9 photos, all with the genre tag 'nature') I get 9 entries, all with the name 'nature' and quantity 1. I have tried using a for await ...of loop, but either that's not the right thing to be using or I'm implementing it incorrectly because it returns the same problematic array. When I log `existingGenre` to the console, I always get `undefined`, so I'm pretty sure that the problem is that `tempFilterList` isn't updating fast enough for the forEach loop to find the new values that I'm `push`ing in.

How can I get my for loop to wait for the `tempFilterList` array to update?

Comment: Are you sure it's the loop not finishing that's the problem and not the implementation itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.find()` is missing a return statement

```js
const existingGenre = tempFilterList.find((entry) => {
  // add `return`:
  return entry.name === photo.genre;
});
```

```js
class Photos {
  filterList = []
  photos = []

  setFilterList() {
    const tempFilterList = [];
    this.photos.forEach((photo) => {
      const existingGenre = tempFilterList.find((entry) => {
        return entry.name === photo.genre;
      });
      if (existingGenre) {
        existingGenre.quantity += 1;
      } else {
        tempFilterList.push({
          name: photo.genre || 'generic',
          quantity: 1,
        });
      }
    });
    this.filterList = tempFilterList;
  }
}

const photos = new Photos()

photos.photos = [
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
  { genre: 'nature' },
]

photos.setFilterList()

console.log('filterList:', photos.filterList)
```

Comment: :o you're absolutely correct, thank you very much. I feel like a doofus now

Comment: @mFsGiant :D happens to all of us. Cheers mate